# Set a value for all field in desired column? javascript

Tags: development, javascript, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013, office-365-developer

i have the following solution:

in my SP list called QUIZ i have a column named `koha` [image]

i also have a userinterface that is build via XML in my javascript solution 
[image]
 the current setting are when you create a new item via userinterface the Koha field is unique for each item. the name of Koha field in my xml is 'timer'.
I want if value in Koha field in UserInterface is 35 than set value of 35 for all field in `koha` column

thanks all

Comment: I think this answer is very close to your requirement. [How to update multiple items in sharepoint list online using javascript](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/141987/how-to-update-multiple-items-in-sharepoint-list-online-using-javascript)

Comment: Why wasn't it useful? Your question states you want to update all items in the list.